# PHP mysqli->connect to remote host inserts local hostname with username

Tags: php, mysqli, remote-access

This code runs from my Mac, but it is not running from a hosted server. The error message is:

```
Tue, 11 Jun 2013 14:46:48 -0700
Remote host: my_remoteserver.com
Remote user: my_user
Remote db: my_remotedbname
mysqli Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localsystem.com' (using password: YES)
```

For some reason the local apache/php system is attaching "@localsystem.com" to my userid. What configuration parameter can I adjust to prevent that?

When run from my Mac, the output is, as expected:

```
Tue, 11 Jun 2013 18:03:41 -0400
mysqli Connection was OK!
Show databases returned 2 rows.
information_schema ()
my_remotedatabase ()
```

the code:

```
<?php
$hostname = "my_remoteserver.us";
$user = "my_user";
$password = "_today0613";
$dbname   = "my_remotedbname";

echo date(r, time());
echo "Remote host: " . $hostname . "<br/>";
echo "Remote user: " . $username . "<br/>";
echo "Remote db: " . $dbname . "<br/>";


$con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "mysqli Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } else { echo "mysqli Connection was OK!<br />\n";}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = $con->query("SHOW databases")) {
    printf("Show databases returned %d rows.<br />\n", $result->num_rows);

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)<br />\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
    }
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();

    }
$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: What is localsystem.com ?? Can you echo the connection variables to ensure they are what you expected before you connect? Maybe one got changed somehow.

Comment: updated code in original post as well. I added code: echo "Remote host: " . $hostname . "<br/>";
echo "Remote user: " . $username . "<br/>";
echo "Remote db: " . $dbname . "<br/>"; - and it returns the userid without the @localsystem.com

Comment: Its possible that that system has a config somewhere to auto append the @localsystem.com?

Comment: yes, most certainly. But where? and how do I override it, or change it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got remote access enabled for the user? If not, login as root or another administrative user to your mysql and issue:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  ‘USERNAME’@‘IP’  IDENTIFIED  BY  ‘PASSWORD’;
```

Change:

The `*.*` stands for All schemas, all tables.. Specific access to one schema (recommended):

`SchemaName.*`

`username` to the user that you want access to

`ip` Change to the IP that the server is on

`identified by password` substitute `password` for the users password.

Then issue:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

or restart the entire mysql service

Comment: As I said - this runs from my Mac here on my desktop, connecting to the remote server "my_remoteserver.com" - I decided to test it by putting it on another server I help manage - call it "localsystem.com" - and that system is inserting its own "@localsystem.com" to the userid for some bizarre reason.

Comment: and I do not want to add the @localsystem.com to the userid because the database may be accessed from a number of different remote servers during development and production.

Comment: Help! can anyone help me with this problem - I've moved on to other things, but still need this to work correctly. The issue is not solved by adding user@remotesystem, I don't think. The issue is that my mysql server is appending @localsystem to the UID. That is the behavior I'm trying to change.

Comment: Are you using the FQDN? or the IP to identify the system?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a problem. Likely to be the cause.

```
$con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password,$dbname);
```

In your debugging it uses.

```
echo "Remote user: " . $username . "<br/>";
```

These need to be the same variable. The system by default is probably using @localsystem.com if it is not filled.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are saying. PHP mysqli_connect is using the remote $hostname properly, but for some reason it is adding @localhost to the username. This is the barrier I cannot get over or around. This is new behavior for me, some setting that I cannot discover.

Comment: In the debugging statement you have a different variable name. probably mismatched names somewhere. So you are using the default somehow.

Comment: Well. Duh. Thanks for pointing that little item out. I did not even see it. However, one of the other fellows added some debugging lines, and he might have added it incorrectly ($user/$username). I have opened a ticket with HostGator, and it seems adding the @localhost is a default in cPanel, and they will offer no way to get rid of it. So I just have to figure out how to work around it. This default is causing problems in other scripts as well, and it did not work this way in a Plesk environment on another hosting service.

Comment: As is often the case here, we eventually solve things on our own. I have solved this mystery, or come close.